# Is possible that a user connect server iis, it can create new sites, without be admin user?

Tags: iis, server

I am trying to connect to server in iis, but I dont have correct permissions, because i don't see server in list, I tried to connect, but show me an error

> Could not connect to the specified computer Details : Unable to connect to the remote server.

I have been read some documentation, I found a temporary solution, give permissions for a windows user o group to access a site, but they can't create other sites, Is possible that user can connect to server without be admin user, And it can create a new sites.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753695(v=ws.10)

thanks

Comment: Creating a site is clearly something only an administrator should do. You cannot delegate that to non-admin.